# Can't find why IE 8-9 goes in quirks mode on an HTML5 page

Tags: html, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, quirks-mode

This is the URL: http://sdc.sciamanna.eu/
IE 8 and 9 goes to quirks mode and I don't know why.

I've spent the last two hours looking for a solution, searching here in SO, in Google, line by line in my html page, but I can't find what is causing IE to go in quirks mode.

What I did so far:

- removed an HTML comment before the DOCTYPE.
- removed all the conditional html tags (now rolled back, since nothing changed), thinking that modernizr may take care of that
- replaced the meta `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />` with `<?php header("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge,chrome=1");?>` as I had validation issues (but again, rolled back as it wasn't the cause)
- did all the stuff above at the same time (this only helped me to get a green light from W3C validator, for what is worth)
- slammed my head on the desk a couple of times: this, really, didn't help

Really, I can't get out of this issue.
I don't know if this happens with IE10 as well, but I'm quite sure it does.

**UPDATE**

[This page](http://demo.designmonstr.com/html/iblink/) (the HTML theme from which is based my WordPress theme) works.
It doesn't even use Modernizr, but just "http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js": I've started using the same script, but things where even worse when, as almost nothing were rendered properly; modernizr at least manage to make most of the things works properly.
But the fact that the default html5shim works in the original theme, only give me another confirmation that there must be something wrong in my implementation: I just can't find what.

Both themes (iBlink and mine) makes use of HTML5 tags, but the original one has no issues at all, while mine, as you can see, does.

Comment: Your document doesn't validate for me: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsdc.sciamanna.eu%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: When I open the site IE renders in "Standard Mode". I have IE8. Does your problem affect IE9 only?

Comment: @PeeHaa: as I've written, it did validate when I've applied all the changes together. Right now I rolled back some of the changes as they didn't make sense. If I'm right, you only get a validation issue related to '<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />'

Comment: @JanPetzold: right now with IE9 only, but the client says the problem is there with IE8 as well. If you look at the 3 boxes under the gallery with Chrome (to say one) you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the actual solution it to use Modernizr: I wasn't see immediate results, probably because of browser caching.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the `section` HTML-tag. This is not supported on IE8, so anything can happen :) It still renders though, but I'm not surprised the browser falls back to Quirks mode. Did you try to replace all HTML5-tags with DIVs or setting `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` ?

Btw. you can easily "simulate" IE8 by going to the developer tools and changing the browser mode to IE8.

Comment: I use Modernizr, that is suppose to solve html5 issues with IE8, if any.
As written above, I do use X-UA-Compatible.
Is not a matter of "simulatin" IE8: I know how to do it and this is how I've found out that it goes in quirksmode. And from there I see that it recognize HTML5 tags such secion, thanks to modernizr. The theme from what is based this site works without issues, therefore there must be something wrong in my site and is not HTML5 the issue.

Comment: IE's rendering mode is determined before any Javascript is executed, therefore Modernizr won't make a difference here.

Comment: @JanPetzold very good point. I'm running into the reported issue as well. Somehow my doctype is being changed from <!DOCTYPE html> to <!-- DOCTYPE html -->. I suspected Modernizr, but you've got a point.